# which role-permission database design?

Tags: database-design, optimization, security, schema, database-recommendation

I want to manage roles and permissions. Most of designs on web look like this

tables:

```
Users
Roles
UserRoles
Permissions
RolePermissions
```

Here, what is `permissions`? I am thinking for such a design instead:

```
Users
Roles
UserRoles
Permissions
```

In this design, `Roles` is supposed to be:

```
   id   |     name
```

while `permissions` is supposed to be:

id  |  role_id  |  section  |  action

`permissions` defines which role in which section has what action control. something like this:

```
id  |  role_id  |  section  |  action

1   |     2     |  posts    | edit
2   |     2     |  posts    | add
3   |     2     |  posts    | delete
4   |     3     |  users    | approve
5   |     3     |  users    | edit
6   |     4     |  articles | delete
7   |     2     |  users    | givepermission
```

It uses two strings instead of an extra table and numbers. Also checking it on PHP seems easier.

Does this design have problem? And is it recommended by you according to your experiences?

Comment: In this form nothing will prevent you having an action of 'nunvbfb n!  vnjkvfk@' for the section 'jiojh nfuhn y748jkl tj'.  Or anything else.  You should at least create a table for sections and an other for actions.  (In the structure you mentioned first, a permission would be a section-action pair in your terminology, I think.  Then it is coupled to the given roles.)

Comment: is being coupled a wrong idea?

Comment: No, not at all - but I see I wasn't completely clear.  They should be coupled to the roles in a separate table to avoid redundancy (say (posts/edit) can belong to role 2 and 3, your table above would contain this section-action pair twice).

Comment: All the RDBMS I have worked with have similar functionality built in. I have never needed to implement it myself.

Comment: You could check out Spring Security's schema here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html